# How to get the Chrome download indicator to work when serving a file through Actix_web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rust, actix-web

I have a React front-end application that has a download button on a page.
When I click the download it hits my file serving URL and downloads the file to the browser's memory first and then it downloads to the system and I get to see the download indicator.

However, I don't want this functionality. I want the browser to show the download indicator as soon as my API responds with data.

I did some research and found that for Chrome or any browser to show a download indicator it needs to first get the `content-length` header in the response header, but the file I am transferring is quite big about 3.7 GB so I choose Streams to send data.

But for streaming data it does not support the `content-length` header, I tried passing it to my response but the 'content-length' header was just not showing up.
I did some more research and got to know that using `content-range` might work but I did not get any luck even with that.

I use the `async_streams` crate of Rust to create a stream of my file and then I send it over using `actix_web` like so:

```
Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().content_type("application/x-zip-compressed").insert_header((header::CONTENT_RANGE, format!("bytes 0-1023/{}", file_size))).insert_header((header::CONTENT_DISPOSITION,format!("attachment; filename=\"USL.zip\""),)).streaming(my_data_stream))
```

Since this is a large file I am avoiding loading the entire file into the memory and sending it as my API is running on a VM with a specific size and restrictions.

Here is my entire code:

```
#[get("/api/v1/download/file.zip")]
pub async fn download_file_zip(req: HttpRequest, credential: BearerAuth) -> Result<HttpResponse> {

let file_path = "/path/to/file/Package.zip";
debug!("File path was set to {}", file_path);

if let Ok(file_metadata) = fs::metadata(&file_path) {
    let file_size = file_metadata.len();
    debug!("File size: {} bytes", file_size);
    let mut chunk = vec![0u8; 10 * 1024 * 1024]; // Adjust the chunk size as needed
    if let Ok(mut file) = File::open(file_path) {
        debug!("File was opened successfully");
        let my_data_stream = stream! {
            let mut chunk = vec![0u8; 10 * 1024 * 1024]; // Adjust the chunk size as needed
            loop {
                match file.read(&mut chunk) {
                    Ok(n) => {
                        if n == 0 {
                            break;
                        }
                        info!("Read {} bytes from file", n);
                        yield Result::<Bytes, std::io::Error>::Ok(Bytes::from(chunk[..n].to_vec()));
                    }
                    Err(e) => {
                        eprintln!("Error reading file: {}", e);
                        yield Result::<Bytes, std::io::Error>::Err(e);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        debug!("Sending response...");
        Ok(HttpResponse::Ok()
            .content_type("application/x-zip-compressed")
            .insert_header((header::CONTENT_RANGE, format!("bytes 0-1023/{}", file_size)))
            .insert_header((
                header::CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                format!("attachment; filename=\"USL.zip\""),
            ))
            .streaming(my_data_stream))
    } else {
        Ok(HttpResponse::NotFound().finish())
    }
} else {
    Ok(HttpResponse::NotFound().finish())
  }
}
```

Here are some screenshots to help you understand better:

[image]

as you can see here I have pressed my download button 2 times and both times it downloads the file into the browser's memory first and then Chrome downloads it to my system.

Here are the list of headers I am passing:
[image]

Here is my frontend Receiving side of code:

```
fetch(apiUrl, requestOption)
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      // If the response status is OK, initiate the download
      const reader = response.body.getReader();
      const stream = new ReadableStream({
        start(controller) {
          function push() {
            reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
              if (done) {
                controller.close();
                return;
              }
              controller.enqueue(value);
              push();
            })
          }
          push();
        }
      });

      return new Response(stream, { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream" } });
    } else {
      console.error('Download failed with status:', response.status);
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.style.display = 'none';
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'file.zip'; // Provide a default filename
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error while downloading:', error);
  });
```

I am out of ideas please let me know if I can do something differently to send and receive large files.

I specifically want the download indicator to be shown when the Data is received at the front end normally how it happens in most cases.

Thank you!